# SEO/Google: Does Google bot properly handle break <br /> tags in an <h1>?

Tags: seo, html, search-engines, google-search

Thinking about keywords in headings on pages. When Google crawls the page, and comes across this:

```
<h1>First Keyword<br />
Second Long Tail<br />
Keyword</h1>
```

It's smart enough to know that those `<br />` tags are spaces, right?

What about this scenario?

```
<h1><img src="First Keyword" /><br />
<img src="a.png" alt="Second Long Tail" /><br />
<img src="b.png" alt="Keyword" /></h1>
```

How might it rank the second keyword? Just curious here.

Comment: In your second example, do you really want to use the `src` attribute, or do you intend to use `alt`?

Comment: Sorry, typo. I updated it.

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaken, as for the first scenario, Google will ignore the breaks and index the header as normal and as for the second scenario, Google will ignore the header altogether- it not indexable. Google is interested in indexing text- not HTML and certainly not binary resource files. However, Google will pay attention to some HTML elements such as the image alt text and so forth. The URLs for your images will not show up in the SERPs nor be indexed in the classic sense as you have specified in option 2. If you are trying something tricky, don't. Unless it is purely a style choice, option 2 does not make sense. I used breaks in headers before and that is okay. As far as SEO is concerned, there are no tricks that you should try except honest and straight forward content. I suggest keeping it simple.

Comment: I meant alt. src was a typo...